# Flutter - GraphQL Support

Tags: flutter, graphql

Can someone help us with the following

1. Does google have any plans to support an official graphQL Client in near future? If not any chances with apollo graphQl clinet? as i dont see any official support for Flutter - GraphQL integration.
   n.

Answer (score 0):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/graphql_flutter 
A GraphQL client for Flutter, bringing all the features from a modern GraphQL client to one easy to use package. 
Github https://github.com/zino-app/graphql-flutter 
There are two example you can check https://github.com/zino-app/graphql-flutter/tree/master/examples

code snippet for query

```
String readRepositories = """
  query ReadRepositories(\$nRepositories: Int!) {
    viewer {
      repositories(last: \$nRepositories) {
        nodes {
          id
          name
          viewerHasStarred
        }
      }
    }
  }
""";

Query(
  options: QueryOptions(
    document: readRepositories, // this is the query string you just created
    variables: {
      'nRepositories': 50,
    },
    pollInterval: 10,
  ),
  // Just like in apollo refetch() could be used to manually trigger a refetch
  // while fetchMore() can be used for pagination purpose
  builder: (QueryResult result, { VoidCallback refetch, FetchMore fetchMore }) {
    if (result.errors != null) {
      return Text(result.errors.toString());
    }

    if (result.loading) {
      return Text('Loading');
    }

    // it can be either Map or List
    List repositories = result.data['viewer']['repositories']['nodes'];

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: repositories.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final repository = repositories[index];

        return Text(repository['name']);
    });
  },
);
```

Comment: Hi chunhunghan, thanks for your response, but i have one more query, in the current version of graphql_flutter they have dropped  document: readRepositories, and added documentnode : readRepositories and also finding it hard to implement along with providers.

Comment: also can you point me to a good implementation with a provider package. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not have graphql server. can't help.